# How to pass a dynamic variable into an Ansible role

Tags: ansible

For each of our servers (webs and perls), we have different mount points for each type of servers. So for web servers, I want to use the entries for "web_mounts" and perls would be "perl_mounts."

If I hard code "web_mounts" into the "with_items," it works fine. Otherwise, it tells me "nfs_group" is undefined.

## Top Level

```
roles:
  - { role: webs, nfs_group: "web_mounts" }
```

## roles/nfs_mounts/vars/main.yml

```
---
web_mounts:
  - { source: "nfs.local:/nfs/web1, dest: "/web1", opts: "rw,noatime" }
  - { source: "nfs.local:/nfs/web2, dest: "/web2", opts: "rw,noatime" }

perl_mounts:
  - { source: "nfs.local:/nfs/perl1, dest: "/perl1", opts: "rw,noatime" }
  - { source: "nfs.local:/nfs/perl2, dest: "/perl2", opts: "rw,noatime" }
```

## roles/nfs_mounts/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Create fstab entries
  mount: fstab=nfs state=present opts="{{ item.opts }}" src="{{ item.source }}" name="{{ item.dest }}"
  with_items: "{{ nfs_group }}"
```

Comment: Note there's a typo/missing quote in your `vars`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your mounts in a dict like this:

```
---
mounts:
  web_mounts:
    - { source: "nfs.local:/nfs/web1", dest: "/web1", opts: "rw,noatime" }
    - { source: "nfs.local:/nfs/web2", dest: "/web2", opts: "rw,noatime" }
  perl_mounts:
    - { source: "nfs.local:/nfs/perl1", dest: "/perl1", opts: "rw,noatime" }
    - { source: "nfs.local:/nfs/perl2", dest: "/perl2", opts: "rw,noatime" }
```

And access dict elements like this:

```
- name: Create fstab entries
  mount: fstab=nfs state=present opts="{{ item.opts }}" src="{{ item.source }}" name="{{ item.dest }}"
  with_items: "{{ mounts[nfs_group] }}"
```

As for *"nfs_group is undefined"* error, check that you call roles correctly – your role name is "nfs_mounts" and your top level playbook applies role "webs".